# How to change Oracle Applications (forms) look and feel by adding custom skins

Tags: java, oracle, look-and-feel, skinning

I would like to skin Oracle Applications (the Human Resources professional user interface forms), similar to how you skin normal Java Swing applications; but can't find anything on Google on how to do this.

The application allows you to change the look and feel and colour, using these profile options:

Java Look And Feel
Java Colour Scheme

It also provides two examples of look and feel. Basically I need to know the following. If I download a swing skin like Nimbus, where would I put this on the Oracle Application server that would allow it to be selectable by the Java Look and Feel profile option? You seem to also need to add it to the LOOK_AND_FEEL lookup, but I'm not sure where on the server it then picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Francois Degrelle's Forms Look and Feel project.  This is not an official Oracle extension but [Oracle do endorse it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/community-paper-forms-look-and-feel-131989.pdf).

It might not be the solution you want to use, but you could pick up some tips about indstallation.  [Find out more](http://fdtool.free.fr/LAF/doc/Oracle_Forms_Look_and_Feel_project.htm).

Comment: That seems very complicated. Can't you just put a skin file you downloaded in the correct directory?